# how to add header "UNH" to UNEdifactInterchange41 Object in smooks

Tags: edi, smooks, edifact

I have to create an mscons export of energy values. I created a bit of code from some examples I found, but now I stuck.  MSCONS needs an UNB and an UNH header.
I can add the UNB header to the UNEdifactInterchange41 object, but I don't find a method to attach the UNH header.

Here's my code so far:

```
import org.milyn.SmooksException;
import org.milyn.edi.unedifact.d16b.D16BInterchangeFactory;
import org.milyn.edi.unedifact.d16b.MSCONS.*;
import org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.model.r41.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.model.r41.types.MessageIdentifier;
import org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.model.r41.types.Party;
import org.milyn.smooks.edi.unedifact.model.r41.types.SyntaxIdentifier;

public class EDI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {

        D16BInterchangeFactory factory = D16BInterchangeFactory.getInstance();
        UNEdifactInterchange41 edi = new UNEdifactInterchange41();       
        Mscons mscons = new Mscons();

        /*UNB*/
        UNB41 unb = new UNB41();
        unb.setSender(null);
        Party sender = new Party();
        sender.setInternalId(getSenderInternalId());
        sender.setCodeQualifier(getSenderCodeQualifier());
        sender.setId(getSenderId());
        SyntaxIdentifier si=new SyntaxIdentifier();
        si.setVersionNum("3");
        si.setId("UNOC");
        unb.setSyntaxIdentifier(si);
        unb.setSender(sender);
        edi.setInterchangeHeader(unb);
        /*UNH*/
        UNH41 unh = new UNH41();
        MessageIdentifier mi=new MessageIdentifier();
        mi.setTypeSubFunctionId("MSCONS");
        mi.setControllingAgencyCode("UN");
        mi.setAssociationAssignedCode("2.2h");

        String refno=createRefNo();
        unh.setMessageIdentifier(mi);


        /* How to attach UNH? */


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you got it almost right, you need to attach the UNH to message and not the opposite:

```
mi.setMessageIdentifier(unh);
```

You have an example there if you need:
https://github.com/ClaudePlos/VOrders/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/vo/integration/edifact/EdifactExportPricat.java

Comment: thank you so much, Luc! I didn't had UNEdifactMessage41.. I'm not sure I would have found it without your help.